When native Chinese speakers hear their native language, do both their left and right temporal lobes activate, while it's only the left for English?
張鳳蓮's 2016 master's thesis writes:

心理學家 Sophie Scott 於倫敦醫院所作的實驗顯示英文母語者聽到母語英語時，左側顳葉顯示活動的影像，而漢語母語者聽到漢語時，左右兩側顳葉都在活動。
[Google Translate]: Experiments conducted by psychologist Sophie Scott at a London hospital showed that when native English speakers heard their native English, the left temporal lobe showed activity, while when native Chinese speakers heard Chinese, both left and right temporal lobes were active.
左側顳葉通常負責把個別聲音堆砌成字，右顳葉負責處理音韻及聲調。研究結果表示漢語的識辨處理過程有異於英語的處理過程。
[Google Translate]: The left temporal lobe is usually responsible for stacking individual sounds into words, and the right temporal lobe is responsible for processing phonemes and tones. The results of the study indicate that the recognition processing process of Chinese is different from the processing process of English.

I believe the source for this claim is this work:

Scott, S., Rosen, S., Faulkner, A., Meng, Y., Wise, R., Warren, J., Spitsyna, G., Narain, C., 2003. Speech in the brain: interactions with learning, faces and cultural differences. Paper presented at Royal Society Summer Science Exhibition, London.

and the relevant link was this, but it's broken now (and I can't access it through Archive.org [which is currently experiencing intermittent downtime]).  So I wasn't able to track down the original article.  This research was mentioned in the BBC News and The Guardian.
I'm interested in whether or not the above description correctly represents this research, and whether or not this research has withstood the test of time (the paper was published 21 years ago).
Question: When native Chinese speakers hear their native language, do both their left and right temporal lobes activate, while it's only the left for English?

That sounds really suspect. Maybe look for brain activation while using English from other sources. Alternative, if you have a university affiliation, ask the librarian for that work.

Aight, it's early in the morning here, and I can't get my thoughts in a convincing order, so bullet points it is:

As a meta point, the original research sets off some red flags:

It's only a master thesis
It's hard to access, suggesting dubious publication
The English title of the Chinese version doesn't match anything said about this paper (and it's bad)


Apparently, working for BBC News or the Guardian does not require activation of either brain half, because I have no idea how you take the leap from 'showed activity in different and more in diverse areas' to 'it must be more difficult'

Of course, none of this makes your question on replication irrelevant, so let's get to the meat.

As a rule of thumb, any research that suggests something non-trivial only happens in area X of the brain is lying to you (or rather, simplifying the situation). The Wikipedia article is a decent intro.
Said article also tells you the keyword you want to look into: Lateralization

So, what's up with the lateralization of English and Chinese?

this paper says there is a shared center, with an additional one for Chinese (I think)
this one also seems pretty deep into the weeds; I don't get its conclusion at a glance
here is one essentially saying both languages use both hemispheres

It seems to be hard to get a final answer here. I can't find a relevant meta analysis. You will notice how most of these studies (and others that you can find with the keyword) often have big differences and research special cases, making them not really comparable (e.g. older people, language learners, people with autism, this brain scan method or that, characters, text, listening, speaking, ...)
My conclusion: Are Chinese and English handled by the exact same average brain regions? Likely not. Is there an obvious, neat pattern akin to Chinese using 'more of the brain' or a nice right-left split? Likely not.
Hope that helps :)

Thanks!  Those papers certainly make it clear the claim is oversimplified, and the news articles that claim e.g. "Chinese is harder to learn than English" almost seem like works of fiction.
